# How to change font colour based on ID number from output

Tags: php, json

so I have a JSON url that I am pulling post titles from and that all works, but what I want to do is have it so that depending on the userID, determines what colour the post would be, so for example if the userID is 1 then make the font colour red.

```
$data = file_get_contents($json_url); 
$posts = json_decode($data);

foreach ($posts as $post) {

echo $post->title . '<br>';
 }
```

Comment: Where the `userId` came from?

Comment: Welcome. Where are you having problems? Creating the `if` clause? Defining the color?

Comment: You can wrap your `$post->title` in html and then set the color there; for example:

`'<p style="color: red">' . $post->title . '</p>'`

Then all you need is `if` statements to determine the color. The more colours you need, the likelihood is you'll need to implement a more intelligent solution as opposed to increasing the number of if statements you use. 

Let me know if you want more info or if I've missed the point of your question.

Comment: @TamilvananN the userID will come from the $posts data that is being pulled

Comment: @kerbholz Thank you and it's creating the if clause in general, I'm unsure of how to start it exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
if($post->userId == 1){
    echo "<div style='color:red'>".$post->title ."</div><br>";
    }
elseif ($post->userId == 1){
    echo "<div style='color:blue'>".$post->title ."</div><br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your title in a `<span>` or `<div>` and give it a class related to the userId:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  echo sprintf('<span class="titleUser%d">%s</span>', $post->userId, $post->title);
}
```

(assuming `$post->userId` is your userId, change this to fit your needs)

You'll end up with different classes like `titleUser1`, `titleUser27` etc.

Define the styles for the classes you want to change in your CSS:

```
.titleUser1 {color: red}
.titleUser27 {color: green}
```

No need to create `if` clauses for every user, just add a new class to your style when needed.